# Get from .dll executors assembly

Tags: c#, assemblies

I'am creating framework in C#, and i need to get assembly of executor. That means that i need assembly of .exe that is using my .dll.

... `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` returns .dll assembly not assembly of .exe.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself; use this method: `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`

Comment: @gipinani he did find the answer to the problem